# How to put a method with aguments on a different thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the method that takes an argument from external dll through a delegate pointer:

```
public delegate void NotificationsCallbackDelegate(CinectorNotification message);

NotificationsCallbackDelegate notificationsCallbackDeleg;
IntPtr notificationsCallbackPointer;


notificationsCallbackDeleg = NotificationsCallback;
notificationsCallbackPointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(notificationsCallbackDeleg);
instance.SetNotificationsCallback(notificationsCallbackPointer);

 private void NotificationsCallback(CinectorNotification notif)
 {
   Log.AppendText("[" + notif.timestamp + "] " + notif.type + ": " + notif.message + Environment.NewLine);
 }
```

So, input argument 'message' is something that can be passed by dll at any time during the application flow, whenever the external engine generates some log. It is like an event.

I use the following code to put a method on a new thread:

```
private void startNotifications()
{
   Thread NotificationsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(NotificationsCallback));
   NotificationsThread.IsBackground = true;
   NotificationsThread.Start();
}
```

However, the method `NotificationsCallback(CinectorNotification notif)` takes in an argument and therefore doesn't match the delegate for ThreadStart. So how would I put a method like this on a different thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Task.Run and supply it a lambda where you call NotificationsCallback with whatever arguments you need  For example:

```
private void startNotifications()
{
   Task.Run(() => NotificationsCallback(arg1, arg2) );
}
```

This will result in NotificationsCallback being run on on a ThreadPool thread.

For more information on Task.Run, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, but the problem is that I do not call this method anywhere explicitly. It fires whenever I receive a notification through a delegate from some external api.

Comment: I don't totally understand the problem.  You said the callback takes an argument.  Where do you want the value of that argument to come from?

Comment: It comes from external dll. Please see the updated code

Answer (score 1):

You code would work if there is a method passed in the parameter is parameterless.

If you want a parametrised thread, you should use another overload of the `Thread` constructor which will take [`ParameterizedThreadStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

`Start` method on the thread is then called with an argument which is passed on to the thread method like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(WorkerMethod);
thread.Start(35); //for example 35

void WorkerMethod(object parameter)
{
    int? intParameter = parameter as int?; //for example
    if (intParameter.HasValue)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

You can also use `Task`, which is a more modern approach to multi-threading.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => WorkerMethod(35)); //for example 35
```

Or `Task.Run` in .NET 4.5 and newer. In task one can pass as many paramaters as wanted (without creating a container for them) and also the parameters can be strongly typed... not just `object`.

Comment: Parhaps provide a link to the `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate? That would explain why the parameter has to be an `System.Object` Then you could point out that a common way to pass multiple parameters is a StateObject that carries all the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ThreadStart` you could use `ParameterizedThreadStart` and pass the required parameters in `Thread.Start`.